# My Ruby pik is crashing: "can't dup NilClass"

Tags: ruby, pik

It goes like this (note that I enabled echo in pik.bat). All latest release versions downloaded today (though there may be some collisions with old software not properly uninstalled)

> F:\ruby\pik>pik.bat
>
> F:\ruby\pik>"F:\ruby\pik\pik_runner.exe" "F:\ruby\pik\pik.bat"
>
> There was an error.
>    Error: can't dup NilClass
>
> in: pathname.rb:205:in `dup'
>     in: pathname.rb:205:in`initialize'
>     in: pik/commands/add_command.rb:17:in `new'
>     in: pik/commands/add_command.rb:17:in`add'
>     in: pik/commands/add_command.rb:13:in `execute'
>     in: pik_runner:27

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Pik runs in its own environment, so make sure the Ruby environment is in the PATH. For example, if Pik is installed in `C:\tools`, path should be modified as following

`C:\tools;C:\Ruby\ruby-1.8.7-p374\bin;`

Answer (score 0):

You must install pik .30 or higher.